# Cloud Code Push User and Queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to do the following, query the number of WorkOrders pending with the New status for tomorrow. Query the Employee (pointer on the install object) and then get the devices I need to push to, and finally send the push. Im not really all that familar with JavaScript so I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

The error I'm getting is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in main.js:134

which would be the send part where the success and error functions come in right after alert (i.e. },{ is the line it says is the error)

Any ideas or how i can do this? I have very little experience so this is a learning as I go type thing.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("NotifyTomNextDaySO", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.query("WorkOrders");
var workOrderObjs = new []
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
var startTomorrow = tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var endTomorrow = tomorrow.setHours(23,59,59,59);
var numberFound = 0;
query.greaterThan("date", startTomorrow);
query.lessThan("date", endTomorrow);
query.equalTo("status", "New");
query.count({
    success : function(count) {
        numberFound = count;
        var userQuery = new Parse.query("Employees");
        userQuery.equalTo("firstName", "Tom");
        userQuery.equalTo("lastName", "Sedletzeck");
        userQuery.find({
            success : function(employeeFound) {
                var installQuery = Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
                query.equalTo("employee", employeeFound);
                Parse.Push.send({
                    where: installQuery,
                    data :{
                        alert: (numberFound + " work orders promised for tomorrow with a status of New.");
                    }
                }, {
                    success: function() {

                    },
                    error: function() {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

);

EDIT:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("NotifyTomNextDaySO", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query("WorkOrders");
var workOrderObjs = [];
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
var startTomorrow = tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var endTomorrow = tomorrow.setHours(23,59,59,59);
var numberFound = 0;
query.greaterThan("date", startTomorrow);
query.lessThan("date", endTomorrow);
query.equalTo("status", "New");
query.count({
    success : function(count) {
        numberFound = count;
        var userQuery = new Parse.query("Employees");
        userQuery.equalTo("firstName", "Trever");
        userQuery.equalTo("lastName", "Ewing");
        userQuery.find({
            success : function(employeeFound) {
                var installQuery = Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
                query.equalTo("employee", employeeFound);
                Parse.Push.send({
                    where: installQuery,
                    data :{
                        alert: (numberFound + " work orders promised for tomorrow with a status of New.")
                    }
                }, {
                    success: function(error) {
                        response.success("Done");
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        response.error("Error1: " + error);
                    }
                });
            }, error : function(error) {
                response.error("Error2: " + error);
            }
        });
    }, error : function(error) {
        response.error("Error3: " + error);
    }
});
}
);
```

Imm getting an error on Error3: [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            data :{
                alert: (numberFound + " work orders promised for tomorrow with a status of New.");
            }
```

Here you're defining an object, so you shouldn't have a `;`

Since you're now having a spare `;`, you can put it there:

```
var workOrderObjs = new [];
```

That's not mandatory because JS is quirky, but it's strongly recommanded not to rely on the auto-adding of the terminators.

Comment: Alright thank you! But now i get "success/error was not called" fail status. Any idea? I thought i was doing it for each one.

Comment: I think i fixed that, but now i get "Error" for my last one, i updated my code to show.

Comment: I just figured that out as well, do you know what " Cannot call a class as a function at r.default" means? I couldn't find anything on that?

Comment: I don't. But you you try simpliying your query to test what's wrong.